# Multiply cell with several other cells based on a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need to multiply a range of cells with a value that a user inputs in a table.

So if they input the year "2017" in a cell, then the value they input from that year needs to be multiplied with another number from 2017, 2018, and 2019.
The year they input is different, but all numbers need to be multiplied up until 2019 always.

This is how the Excel sheet would sort of look like.
[image]

The idea is that when another table to the right is added below the others, that the "price in 2019" would be calculated automatically. The calculation is included at the top of the screenshot for clarity.

I tried creating a VBA code but it only multiplies the initial value with each value individually, instead of creating a single total number.

```vb
Sub calculate ()
ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In Range("F5:F24")
    If Cell.Value < Range("B7").Value Then
    
    ElseIf Cell.Value >= Range("B7") Then
        Cell.Offset(0,4).Value = Range("B8") * Cell.Offset(0,1).Value
        
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should pay attention to the design of the user interface.

Answer (score 2):

You can get by with a formula without programming:

```
=B8 * Product(Filter($G$5:$G$24, $F$5:$F$24>=B7, 0))
```

Here:

- `B7` is a starting year
- `B8` is a starting price
- `F5:F24` is a **Year** column
- `G5:G24` is a **Price** column

The formula is made for `D7`, so put it there, then copy `D7` to `D12` to
update starting year and price addresses.

Comment: Very nice, use of Excel Formulas, !